# CSS Dropdowns display list over other elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Hello I am trying to make a mostly CSS dropdown with some jQuery handling the showing and form submission. One thing I am struggling with is making it so the dropdown list does not push the other elements down. Any other suggestions are welcome here is my code ( I know shouldnt be using tables at all but have to fit this in a legacy UI so bear with me )

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.js">   </script>
    <style>
        *{padding:0;margin:0;}
        span.icon{
            display:inline;
            height:15px;
            width:15px;
        }
        span.icon.left{
            float:left;
            padding-left:5px;
        }
        span.icon.right{
            float:right;
            padding-right:5px;
        }
        div.dropDown{
            height:20px;
            width:200px;
            margin:10px;
            padding:2px 0;
            cursor:pointer;
            border:1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius:3px;
            -webkit-border-radius:3px;
            -moz-border-radius:3px;
            background-color:#f5f5f5;
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(
                linear,
                left bottom,
                left top,
                color-stop(0, rgb(230,230,230)),
                color-stop(0.84, rgb(255,255,255))
            );
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
                center bottom,
                rgb(230,230,230) 0%,
                rgb(255,255,255) 84%
            );
        }
        div.dropDown:hover{
            border:1px solid #777;
            background-color:#eee;
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(
                linear,
                left bottom,
                left top,
                color-stop(0, rgb(255,255,255)),
                color-stop(0.84, rgb(230,230,230))
            );
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
                center bottom,
                rgb(255,255,255) 0%,
                rgb(230,230,230) 84%
            );
            box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #ccc;
            -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #ccc;
            -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #ccc;
        }
        div.dropDown span{padding-top:1px;}
        span.dropHeader{
            padding-left:10px;
            color:#333;
            text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #fff;
        }
        ul.optionList{
            width:200px;
            display:none;
            border:1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius:0px 0px 3px 3px;
            -webkit-border-radius:0px 0px 3px 3px;
            -moz-border-radius:0px 0px 3px 3px;
            padding:5px 0;
            box-shadow:1px 1px 5px #ccc;
            -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 5px #ccc;
            -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 5px #ccc;
        }
        li.option{
            list-style-type:none;
            padding:3px 2px;
            border:1px solid transparent;
            border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
        }
        li.option:last-child {
            border-bottom:0;
        }
        span.optTitle{
            padding-left:10px;
            color:#333;
        }
        li.option:hover{
            background-color:#FB880C;
            cursor:pointer;
            border:1px solid #cf7310;
            box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 6px #9e5303;
            -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 6px #cf7310;
            -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 6px #cf7310;
        }
        li.option:hover span.optTitle{
            color:#fff;
            text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #9e5303;
        }
        input{clear:both}
        img.dropArrow{width:10px;height:10px;}
        .iconName1 {width:15px;height:15px;background:#333;border:1px solid #000;}
        .iconName2 {width:15px;height:15px;background:#ccc;border:1px solid #333;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>  <br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <form name="search" action="/">
    <table><tr>
    <td>
        <div id="selectName" class="dropDown">
            <span class="icon left"><img src="px.gif" id="sprite" class="iconName1" /></span>
            <span class="dropHeader">Option1</span>
            <span class="icon right"><img src="down-arrow.png" class="dropArrow" /></span>
        </div>
        <ul id="selectName" class="optionList">
            <li id="value0" class="option">
                <span class="icon left"><img src="px.gif" class="iconName1" /></span>
                <span class="optTitle">Option1</span>
            </li>
            <li id="value1" class="option">
                <span class="icon left"><img src="px.gif" class="iconName2" /></span>
                <span class="optTitle">Option2</span>
            </li>
            <li id="value0" class="option">
                <span class="icon left"><img src="px.gif" class="iconName1" /></span>
                <span class="optTitle">Option3</span>
            </li>
            <li id="value1" class="option">
                <span class="icon left"><img src="px.gif" class="iconName2" /></span>
                <span class="optTitle">Option4</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="hidden" id="selectName2" name="selectName" value="" />
    <!--[if IE 6]>
    <select name="selectName">
        <option value="value">Option1</option>
        <option value="value">Option2</option>
        <option value="value">Option3</option>
        <option value="value">Option4</option>
    </select>
    <![endif]-->
        <div id="selectName2" class="dropDown">
            <span class="icon left"><img src="px.gif" id="sprite" class="iconName1" /></span>
            <span class="dropHeader">Option1</span>
            <span class="icon right"><img src="down-arrow.png" class="dropArrow" /></span>
        </div>
        <ul id="selectName2" class="optionList">
            <li id="value0" class="option">
                <span class="icon left"><img src="px.gif" class="iconName1" /></span>
                <span class="optTitle">Option1</span>
            </li>
            <li id="value1" class="option">
                <span class="icon left"><img src="px.gif" class="iconName2" /></span>
                <span class="optTitle">Option2</span>
            </li>
            <li id="value0" class="option">
                <span class="icon left"><img src="px.gif" class="iconName1" /></span>
                <span class="optTitle">Option3</span>
            </li>
            <li id="value1" class="option">
                <span class="icon left"><img src="px.gif" class="iconName2" /></span>
                <span class="optTitle">Option4</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="hidden" id="selectName2" name="selectName" value="" />
    <!--[if IE 6]>
    <select name="selectName2">
        <option value="value">Option1</option>
        <option value="value">Option2</option>
        <option value="value">Option3</option>
        <option value="value">Option4</option>
    </select>
    <![endif]-->
    </td></tr></table>
    </form>
<script>
    $(function(){
        if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == '6.0'){
            $('div.dropDown').hide();
        }
        $('div.dropDown').hover(function(){
            var ultoshow = $(this).attr('id');
            $('ul#'+ultoshow).toggle();
        });
        $('li.option').click(function(){
            var selectName = $(this).parent('ul.optionList').siblings('div.dropDown').attr('id');
            var value = $(this).attr('id');
            var optTitle = $(this).children('span.optTitle').html();    
            var iconClass = optTitle.toLowerCase();

            $(this).parent('ul.optionList').siblings('div.dropDown').children('span.icon').children('img#sprite').attr('class',iconClass);
            $(this).parent('ul.optionList').siblings('div.dropDown').children('span.dropHeader').html(optTitle);
            $('input#'+selectName).attr('value',value); 
            document.search.submit();
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I usually see `position: absolute;` on the dropdown menus.

Comment: Which browser do you need to support? I'm not sure I can bring myself to fix this in IE6, and from the fact that you have `<!--[if IE 6]>`, it looks like you need IE6 support.

Comment: Well I dont want to use a lot of javascript because the app is heavy already and the css :hover class does not work in IE6 so I defaulted to the native <select> and hide the rest of the html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take your menu out of the normal flow of the document, it won't push any other elements out of it's way.

You can do this by adding `position:absolute;` or by using `float:left` or `float:right`.  These commands remove your menu from the rest of the flow, allowing it to go above or below other elements.

Be careful with `float` though, because if you float other elements they can start running into each other.  You should go with `position:absolute` in that case.  If you need to move the position of the menu, use `left: 100px; top:200px` etc.